# How does a power graph of a server running a job look like when there is no CPU power management mechanism deployed

Tags: cpu-usage, electrical-power

Suppose there is no CPU power management mechanism deployed in a server, and i run a job on it and monitoring the power drawn by the server by using a wall power meter, what kind of a profile do you expect when you plot a graph of power vs time ? (assume the wall power meter readings can be recoreded in a file)

**Will the power values of the wall power meter vary as a function of the CPU utilization even when there is no power management mechanism deployed in the server ?**

Answer (score 1):

More than likely "yes" with most modern processors, but that will vary on the engineered power management features of the processor itself.

Comment: @user48838: so, if there is no power management enabled for CPU, the meter readings will not be affected by variation in CPU utlization . correct ?

Comment: That's probably the case for the older processors, not sure if the power management can be completely disabled with a lot of the newer ones. In a lot of "modern" systems, there is usually more than the CPU within a system - e.g. GPU on the video cards can also be in play too.